# Failed SSH attempt from gateway. Is gateway compromised or attacker hiding his IP

Tags: ssh, security, linux-networking

I rent a dedicated server in remote datacenter and when I look at failed SSH log attempts, I am seeing failed attempts from gateway's IP a lot since yesterday.

Is my server provider's gateway really trying to access(maybe compromised) or is the attacker hiding his IP?

What could it be?

Update:

It seems related to datacenter's router misconfiguration. I have two server there. I shutdown both and sent ping request to each.

Server A(malicious attempt from gateway)

```
PING 43.231.113.A (43.231.113.A) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 43.231.113.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Server B. (NO malicious attempt from gateway)

```
PING 43.231.113.B (43.231.113.B) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 103.17.109.211 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Also when ssh to Server A and `echo $SSH_CLIENT` it shows `43.231.113.1`

So every incoming connections are considered coming from gateway.

Comment: Can you give more details such as source ip attempted, what was the count of attempts.

Answer (score 2):

You're not providing much information...
It could be compromised, it could be another machine behind the same gateway that is trying to login into your system spoofing the real gateway's IP, it could be the gateway that is natting connections from outside to inside and the attacker is not hiding at all, and it could be an attacker that is spoofing gateway's address to see how your system is answering (reject, drop, and varius TCP flags...).

I cannot provide a best answer since elements you gave us are quite few.